# i am not sure about this declaration

Tags: javascript, variables, declaration

```
var a = startNode && startNode.a(d)
```

hello guys,
i would like to ask about this declaration. The part "startNode.a(d)" really makes my head hurt. What does it mean? The value "startNode" of a variable "a" calls again the variable "a"?

Thanks guys so much!

H

i edit this, because Tom was asking for the whole code:
the original name for "a" is "path"in this code...i just changed it in my previous question to make it look simple

```
.on("click", function(d, i) 
          {
            var path = startNode && startNode.path(d) || [];
            startNode = d;
            link.style("stroke", function(d) 
            {
              return path.includes(d.source) && path.includes(d.target) ? "#900" : "#999";
            });
            node.attr("r", function(d) 
            {
              return path.includes(d) || startNode == d ? 10 : 4.5;
            });
          });
```

Comment: `startNode` has a property that is a function called `a` which takes an argument, you are calling the function with the variable d as the one and only argument in this case

Comment: It's calling a method of the object in `startNode`.

Comment: It's no different from something like `document.getElementById(d)`. `document` is a variable containing an object, `getElementById` is a of the object  containing a function.

Comment: Can you give us a context about what is `startNode`? Is it a class, a variable you initialised from a lib? The `startNode.a(d)` seems to be a method from your `startNode` object passing the parameter `d`. Please, edit you question and say where `startNode` comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a shorthand way of writing something like this:

```
var a;
if (startNode) {
    a = startNode.a(d);
}
```

If `startNode` is null, then you can't call the `a` method. In terms of the result in `a`, you have 2 cases.

1. If `startNode` is null, then the value of `a` will be null.
2. If `startNode` is not null, then the value of `a` will be the result of the call to the `startNode.a(d);`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` on the left isn't related to `startNode.a(d)` on the right. The variable assignment assumes that `startNode` is an object, and `startNode.a` calls a function; of interest to the value of `a` is whetehr `startNode.a(d)` returns truthy or falsy.